# Java Getting Data From a CSV file Gives Index Out of Bounds Error

Tags: java, csv

I'm new to Java and I'm not sure how to fix this error.

I have a csv file of data which I'll call "myCSVfile.csv". When I open this in a spreadsheet program, I can see that it has 58 columns and 859 rows.

I'm trying to write a function which gets the data from the csv file and returns an array with that data. Here's the code,

```java
public class csvloader {

    static String xSrtPath;
    static double[][] myArray;

    static double[][] setUpArray(){

        myArray = new double[58][859];   // Data has 58 Columns and 859 Rows

        Scanner scanIn = null;
        int Rowc = 0;
        int Row = 0;
        int Colc = 0;
        int Col = 0;
        String InputLine = "";
        double xnum = 0;
        String xfileLocation;

        xfileLocation = "/location/myCSVfile.csv";


        try
        {

            scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xfileLocation)));

            while (scanIn.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] InArray = InputLine.split(",");

                for (int x=0; x<InArray.length; x++)
                {
                    /*
                    Some of the data points are empty or marked with
                    "nan", so this is dealt with by putting a -1 in the
                    array for those data points
                    */
                    if (InArray[x].isEmpty() || InArray[x]=="nan"){
                        myArray[Rowc][x] = -1; 
                    } else {
                        myArray[Rowc][x] = Double.parseDouble(InArray[x]);
                    } 
                }
                Rowc++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }    
        return myArray;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(setUpArray());
    }    
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following "index out of bounds" error,

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 58
[[D@74a14482
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I tried to alter the size of myArray by defining it to be as large as possible, but I still get the same error. Maybe there's something I'm not understanding about Java arrays?

Comment: I guess you meant to use `myArray[x][Rowc]` instead of `myArray[Rowc][x]`. Or `new double[859][58]` instead of `new double[58][859]`. If Rowc goes to 859, it'll obviously have a problem if that dimension of the array is only 58.

Comment: Try printing `InArray.length` before the for loop, what's the length of the array?

Comment: It says that the length of InArray is 1 in each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: You're also never actually reading from the file - `InputLine` doesn't change after it's set for the first time (you may want to avoid setting variables to values you don't plan on using - if you omitted the `= ""`, your code should've given you a compile-time error to indicate that you tried to use the variable before initialising it).

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, I realized I just forgot to write `InputLine = scanIn.nextLine();` in the first line of the while loop. The code seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

Your data has 58 Columns and 859 Rows.
You need to do this :

```
myArray = new double[859][58];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this still gives me an error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 859`. I can make the size of myArray to be really large, like for instance `myArray = new double[10000][10000]; `, but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays are `0-based`.

This means, that for an array of 58 elements, the valid indices vary from `0 to 57`.

You try to read the 59th element of an array containing only 58 elements, hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.